# Open Login component as Separate Page

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular4-forms

I want to open login page in separate. But its opening in inside routeroutlet page. Please help.

PFB below screenshot for your reference.

[image]

Please refer my code below.

**App.Routing.ts :**

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './components/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';

export const AppRoute: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'HomeComponent', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginCoHomeComponentmponent },
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },

];
```

**App.Component.html**

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <app-top-bar></app-top-bar>
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

**App.Module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { APP_BASE_HREF, LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { SelectModule } from 'ng2-select';
import { Ng2Bs3ModalModule } from 'ng2-bs3-modal/ng2-bs3-modal';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { SideBarComponent } from './components/side-bar/side-bar.component';
import { TopBarComponent } from './components/top-bar/top-bar.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './components/dashboard/dashboard.component';

import { AppRoute } from './app.routing';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { Service } from './Service/service';
import { ConfigService } from './Service/config.service';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SideBarComponent,
    TopBarComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    RoleManagementComponent,
    UserManagementComponent,
    UserListComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    HomeComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoute),
    SelectModule,
    Ng2Bs3ModalModule,
    MyDatePickerModule
  ],
  providers: [{ provide: LocationStrategy, useValue: '/AAA', useClass: HashLocationStrategy }, Service, ConfigService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**App.Componenet.html: Modified**

```
 <div id="wrapper">
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
 </div>
```

**Home.component.html Modified**

```
<app-top-bar></app-top-bar>
```

app-top-bar contains top menu and side bar user menus. Its is static component.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this [**medium post**](https://medium.com/@aravind_12433/load-modal-component-dynamically-in-angular-5fda8e1dc3e7) which will help you

Comment: Thanks @Aravind . but I want to show first login page, after successful login , then it goes to home page

Comment: can be achieved using the above post. `ngOnInit` of app component load trigger the modal dialog

Comment: Yes. You are right. we can arrive with popup. During login page popup home page will show behind the screen. That's why im asking to open in a separate page.

Comment: you can hide the contents using either `*ngIf` or `opacity:0` css style. Have a login component which triggers the modal dialog by default and route to it. On `login success` route to home component

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your **App.Component.html** :
change to this : 
`<router-outlet></router-outlet>` so remove `<app-top-bar></app-top-bar>`

In **App.Routing.ts** :
change `{ path: '', redirectTo: 'HomeComponent', pathMatch: 'full' }`

To:

```
{ path: '', component: LoginComponent},
{ path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent,
          children: [
             { path: 'page1', component: Page1Component},
             { path: 'page2', component: Page2Component}
          ]
}
```

In **dashboard.component.html : (Home)**

```
<header-bar>
<side-bar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: If I remove a <app-top-bar></app-top-bar> its act like a separate page. But i want to show a menu and users after successfull login. Those are designed in <app-top-bar></app-top-bar> component. where i have to place top-bar tag now

Comment: You can create a homeComponent for exemple , and put <app-top-bar></app-top-bar> into it and you redirect to homeComponent after successfull login . ex.

if(login()){
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
}

Comment: If i move topbar tag into Home component, after successful login it will move to home page and it have topbar tag alone but <router-outlet></router-outlet> App.Component page. If i click menu in home component. Topbar component is disappear beacuse of <router-outlet placed in App.Component. Really confused

Comment: can you please post your home.component.html and app.componant.html ?

Comment: Posted home.component.html and app.componant.html in question.

Comment: add another <router-outlet></router-outlet> in your Home.component.html and it should works

Comment: How can we add multiple router-outlet in Angular 4 application? Is it possible?

Comment: can you please help me to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52619969/how-to-show-components-in-the-content-area-of-home-component-instead-of-separate @willmaz

Answer (score 0):

i archived this using the service,
**in my jwt service file check the user is logged in or not (token is expired or not)**

```
export class JwtAuthService {

  constructor(public jwtHelper: JwtHelperService) {}
  // ...
  public isAuthenticated(): boolean {
      const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    var isExpired = true;
    // Check whether the token is expired and return
    // true or false
    if(token != null){
      isExpired = !this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token);
      console.log("not null" + isExpired)
    }else{
      isExpired = false;
      console.log("null" + isExpired)
    }
    return isExpired;
    
  }

  }
```

**Then in app.component.html file add the following**

```
<app-tool-bar *ngIf="authService.isAuthenticated() == true"></app-tool-bar>
<app-sidenav-bar *ngIf="authService.isAuthenticated() == true"></app-sidenav-bar>
<router-outlet *ngIf="authService.isAuthenticated() == false"></router-outlet>
```

> Here app-tool-bar and app-sidenav-bar is two separate components. Also in the nav-sidenav-bar component has the  inside it. if user is logged, used the app-tool-bar and app-sidenav-bar component Else we simply use the  without the app tool bar and side navbar
>
> So using this we can load Login page without sidebar and toolbar, all the other pages with toolbar and navbar

*Thank you if you have any doubt please reply to this answer*